# Print Java collections object from its iterator in watch area of debugger of VSCODE or Intellij

Tags: java, debugging, visual-studio-code, intellij-idea, watch

Sometimes I need to observe changes in PriorityQueue or HashSet during debugging the code. I can watch arrays in ***watch*** field of Intellij/VsCode debugger by adding line `Arrays.toString(arr)`. But I can't add collections which uses iterator to print their values.

1. I tried to call the method which prints iterator objects but it failed to call the method.
2. I used steam api as shown below:

```java
Iterable<Integer> iterable =  pq.iterator();//pq is a priorityqueue
        List<Integer> array = StreamSupport
                .stream(iterable.spliterator(), false)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        Iterator<Integer> itr = pq.iterator();
```

But it shows error

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Iterator<Integer> to Iterable<Integer>Java(16777233)

How can I see my iterator objects in watch field during debugging? Or suggest an extension if there is any.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tips/debugging-streams/

Comment: Hi @blurfus, Thanks for replying. But, I need to watch iterator objects.

Comment: You're using the wrong interface, `Iterable<Integer>` should be `Iterator<Integer>`. You can also call `pq.spliterator()` directly.

Comment: Hi @Kayaman, Thanks for commenting. But I tried both Iterable and Iterator, but still it is showing errors. Please add some code example if possible.

Comment: What you mean probably (I'm guessing) is an STL iterator, such as list<int>::iterator...

If you look in the definition of vector<>::iterator you'll see:

`template<class _Ty, class _A = allocator<_Ty> > class vector {
typedef _Tptr iterator;`

So this means that a vector iterator is just a pointer to _Ty, so if you define vector<T>::iterator iter, you can freely cast iter to (T*), just add (T*)iter to the watch window.

list<> however is a bit different, it's iterator is just a pointer to a node in the list. To see it, just add iter._Ptr to the watch window. 

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @JialeDu, I am trying to print itr, (Iterator<Integer> itr = priorityQueueObject.iterator();) which is iterator object of a priority queue in Java.